# What is the purpose of Order By 1 in SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm reading through some old code at work, and have noticed that there are several views with an `order by 1` clause.  What does this accomplish?

Example:

```
Create view v_payment_summary AS
SELECT A.PAYMENT_DATE,
       (SELECT SUM(paymentamount)
          FROM payment B
         WHERE PAYMENT_DATE = B.PAYMENT_DATE
           and SOME CONDITION) AS SUM_X,
       (SELECT SUM(paymentamount)
          FROM payment B
         WHERE PAYMENT_DATE = B.PAYMENT_DATE
           and SOME OTHER CONDITION) AS SUM_Y    
FROM payment A    
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: FYI: It's generally considered bad practice to have an ORDER BY in views, unless you can guarantee the view will only ever be used for presentation.  It's a waste because the ORDER BY will occur 2x if you use the view in another query with an ORDER BY.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: it's generally considered illegal to have an `ORDER BY` in a `VIEW`. Standard SQL does not allow it. SQL Server has outlawed it since 2005. For SQL implementation that do allow it the behaviour is largely undocumented and counter intuitive. In other words, definitely to be avoided.

Comment: @onedaywhen: You're preaching to the choir, but MySQL [permits ORDER BY in views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), as does Oracle IME.  SQL Server allows an ORDER BY if `TOP` is present, and SSMS loves to add `TOP 100 PERCENT`.

Comment: @OMG Ponies@ "MySQL permits ORDER BY in views" -- MySQL permits a `CHECK` constraint in a `CREATE TABLE` but it doesn't actually honour it -- it never actually gets checked! The question is, do these SQL products always *honour* the `ORDER BY` in views e.g. when used in a query that also has an `ORDER BY` does it get sorted twice? Do they even document the behaviour or do you have to look the the execution plans to work it out? I think we know the answers ;)

Comment: FYI Just discovered another use for `ORDER BY 1`...using a cross-apply trick where you want a blank alias. Unfortunately the code e.g. is too big for a comment so I've posted it as an answer below FYI.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

This:

```
ORDER BY 1
```

...is known as an "Ordinal" - the number stands for the column based on the number of columns defined in the SELECT clause.  In the query you provided, it means:

```
ORDER BY A.PAYMENT_DATE
```

It's not a recommended practice, because:

1. It's not obvious/explicit
2. If the column order changes, the query is still valid so you risk ordering by something you didn't intend

Comment: My question asking if there was an upside to using Ordinals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253040/benefits-of-using-sql-ordinal-position-notation

Comment: This only has the `sql` tag. In Standard SQL only column correlation names are allowed in the `OREDER BY` clause because, in theory, the table correlation names are out of scope i.e. should be `ORDER BY PAYMENT_DATE;`. Of course, not all SQL implementations conform to Standards.

Comment: Tested and working in SQL Server `;WITH cte AS(
 SELECT 1 AS Col1, 'z' AS Col2 UNION
 SELECT 2 AS Col1, 'y' AS Col2 UNION
 SELECT 3 AS Col1, 'x' AS Col2 
)

SELECT Col2, Col1 FROM cte ORDER BY 1`

Comment: @OMG Ponies, you mentioned that it's not a recommended practise, so what will be the next best replacement? asking cuz I'm curious.. thanks!

Answer (score 54):

This is useful when you use set based operators e.g. union

```
select cola
  from tablea
union
select colb
  from tableb
order by 1;
```

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. This is the first good reason I've seen so far.

Comment: @Lazer I don't believe so, to perform a union it probably does a sort internally, but this is an implementation question as opposed to a logical output question and in the spirit of SQL there is no need to output the rows in order. Also what if you wish to sort descending? Then you're back to the original problem.

Comment: still... I would rather use `order by tablea.cola`

Comment: @ShaharShokrani that would not work. 
but you can say, I prefer    
   select cola as x
     from tablea
   union
   select colb as x
     from tableb
   order by x;

Comment: select * from (select cola col from tablea union select colb col from tableb) order by col

Answer (score 29):

it simply means sorting the view or table by 1st column of query's result.

Answer (score 8):

I believe in Oracle it means order by column #1

Answer (score 7):

This will sort your results by the first column returned.  In the example it will sort by payment_date.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other answers `ORDER BY 1` orders by the first column.

I came across another example of where you might use it though. We have certain queries which need to be ordered select the same column. You would get a SQL error if ordering by `Name` in the below.

```
SELECT Name, Name FROM Segment ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: why would you do that? why not alias them. [too late comment though]

Comment: @abdulqayyum it's just another way of doing things really. The above example is very simplified. Sometimes the 'Name' column is actually different columns from different tables that you are inserting into another table. Adding a bunch of aliases can make reading more difficult. Another example of where it is used is when selecting many different calculations & want to order by one - without needing to alias. (Although here I would personally prefer an alias to say what the calculation is)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT case when b.salary is null then a.employee_id else b.employee_id end employee_id FROM Employees a FULL JOIN Salaries b on b. employee_id = a.employee_id WHERE b.salary is null or a.employee_id is null order by 1
```

it simply means sorting the view or table by 1st column of the query's result. above this query, the 'employee_id' column is the first column but this column is selected from two tables that's why to use this type of sorting.

Answer (score -2):

An example here from a sample test WAMP server database:-

```
mysql> select * from user_privileges;

| GRANTEE            | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE          | IS_GRANTABLE |
   +--------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | SELECT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | INSERT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | UPDATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | DELETE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | DROP                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | RELOAD                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | SHUTDOWN                | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | PROCESS                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | FILE                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | REFERENCES              | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | INDEX                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | ALTER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | SHOW DATABASES          | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | SUPER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | LOCK TABLES             | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | EXECUTE                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | REPLICATION SLAVE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | REPLICATION CLIENT      | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE VIEW             | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | SHOW VIEW               | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE ROUTINE          | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | ALTER ROUTINE           | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE USER             | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | EVENT                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | TRIGGER                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE TABLESPACE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | SELECT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | INSERT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | UPDATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | DELETE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | DROP                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | RELOAD                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | SHUTDOWN                | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | PROCESS                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | FILE                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | REFERENCES              | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | INDEX                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | ALTER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | SHOW DATABASES          | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | SUPER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | LOCK TABLES             | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | EXECUTE                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | REPLICATION SLAVE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | REPLICATION CLIENT      | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE VIEW             | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | SHOW VIEW               | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE ROUTINE          | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | ALTER ROUTINE           | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE USER             | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | EVENT                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | TRIGGER                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE TABLESPACE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | SELECT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | INSERT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | UPDATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | DELETE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | DROP                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | RELOAD                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | SHUTDOWN                | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | PROCESS                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | FILE                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | REFERENCES              | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | INDEX                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | ALTER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | SHOW DATABASES          | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | SUPER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | LOCK TABLES             | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | EXECUTE                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | REPLICATION SLAVE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | REPLICATION CLIENT      | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE VIEW             | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | SHOW VIEW               | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE ROUTINE          | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | ALTER ROUTINE           | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE USER             | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | EVENT                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | TRIGGER                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE TABLESPACE       | YES          |
| ''@'localhost'     | def           | USAGE                   | NO           |
+--------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
85 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And when it is given additional `order by PRIVILEGE_TYPE` or can be given `order by 3` . Notice the 3rd column (`PRIVILEGE_TYPE`) getting sorted alphabetically.

```
mysql> select * from user_privileges order by PRIVILEGE_TYPE;
+--------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| GRANTEE            | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE          | IS_GRANTABLE |
+--------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | ALTER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | ALTER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | ALTER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | ALTER ROUTINE           | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | ALTER ROUTINE           | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | ALTER ROUTINE           | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE ROUTINE          | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE ROUTINE          | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE ROUTINE          | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE TABLESPACE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE TABLESPACE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE TABLESPACE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE USER             | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE USER             | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE USER             | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | CREATE VIEW             | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | CREATE VIEW             | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | CREATE VIEW             | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | DELETE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | DELETE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | DELETE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | DROP                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | DROP                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | DROP                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | EVENT                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | EVENT                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | EVENT                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | EXECUTE                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | EXECUTE                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | EXECUTE                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | FILE                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | FILE                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | FILE                    | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | INDEX                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | INDEX                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | INDEX                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | INSERT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | INSERT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | INSERT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | LOCK TABLES             | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | LOCK TABLES             | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | LOCK TABLES             | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | PROCESS                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | PROCESS                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | PROCESS                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | REFERENCES              | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | REFERENCES              | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | REFERENCES              | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | RELOAD                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | RELOAD                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | RELOAD                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | REPLICATION CLIENT      | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | REPLICATION CLIENT      | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | REPLICATION CLIENT      | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | REPLICATION SLAVE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | REPLICATION SLAVE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | REPLICATION SLAVE       | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | SELECT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | SELECT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | SELECT                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | SHOW DATABASES          |  YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | SHOW DATABASES          | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | SHOW DATABASES          | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | SHOW VIEW               | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | SHOW VIEW               | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | SHOW VIEW               | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | SHUTDOWN                | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | SHUTDOWN                | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | SHUTDOWN                | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | SUPER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | SUPER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | SUPER                   | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | TRIGGER                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | TRIGGER                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | TRIGGER                 | YES          |
| 'root'@'::1'       | def           | UPDATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'localhost' | def           | UPDATE                  | YES          |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1' | def           | UPDATE                  | YES          |
| ''@'localhost'     | def           | USAGE                   | NO           |     +--------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
85 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

DEFINITIVELY, a long answer and alot of scrolling.
Also I struggled hard to pass the output of the queries to a text file.
Here is how to do that without using the annoying `into outfile` thing-

> tee E:/sqllogfile.txt;

And when you are done, stop the logging-

> tee off;

Hope it adds more clarity.