# MySql sort by highest value with inner join and subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a query that has a sub query that returns a count of records from another table, I'm having trouble ordernar the largest number of this counter

```
SELECT respostas.id,
       respostas.cmm,
       respostas.topico,
       respostas.usuario,
       respostas.resposta,
       perfis.nome,
       perfis.sobrenome,
       respostas.datahora,
       (
           SELECT count(id) 
           FROM likes 
           WHERE respostas.id = resposta
       ) AS total
FROM respostas
INNER JOIN perfis ON respostas.usuario = perfis.id
INNER JOIN likes ON respostas.topico = likes.topico
WHERE respostas.cmm = 28
        AND respostas.topico = 38
ORDER BY respostas.id ASC, total ASC
                LIMIT 0,20`enter code here`
```

I want to sort by the total column and can not.
Sorting by total does not work, only ordered by id

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which column to order by numerically:

```
SELECT           
       (
           SELECT count(id) 
           FROM likes 
           WHERE respostas.id = resposta
       ) AS total,
       respostas.id,
       respostas.cmm,
       respostas.topico,
       respostas.usuario,
       respostas.resposta,
       perfis.nome,
       perfis.sobrenome,
       respostas.datahora
FROM respostas
INNER JOIN perfis ON respostas.usuario = perfis.id
INNER JOIN likes ON respostas.topico = likes.topico
WHERE respostas.cmm = 28
        AND respostas.topico = 38
ORDER BY 1, respostas.id
                LIMIT 0,20
```

[What is the purpose of Order By 1 in SQL select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445118/what-is-the-purpose-of-order-by-1-in-sql-select-statement)

Comment: I think you'll want to remove `total ASC` from the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Updated.