# Generating an "ORDER BY" statement, in a more convenient way

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

In SQL we can use the ["WHERE 1=1 hack"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54954/why-use-where-1-or-where-1-1) to easily generate a WHERE statement in a loop, so we don't need to check if the current iteration is the first one.

**without WHERE 1 :**

```
//I  haven't tried the C++ code below, it's just an example to briefly explain the "hack"

string statement = "WHERE";
for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++)
{
   if (i != 0)
   {
      statement += " AND "; //we don't want to generate "WHERE AND"
   }
   statement += list[i];
}

the generated statement :

WHERE <something_1>
  AND <something_2>
  AND <something_3>
```

**with WHERE 1 :**

```
string statement = "WHERE 1 = 1"; // Added "1 = 1"
for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++)
{
   statement += "AND" + list[i];
}

the generated statement :

WHERE 1 = 1
  AND <something_1>
  AND <something_2>
  AND <something_3>
```

My issue : I need to generate an "ORDER BY" statement, and I was wondering if such a hack also exists for the ORDER BY statement.
I could check if the current iteration in the loop is the last one, but there's maybe a better solution.

```
ORDER BY a DESC,
   b DESC,
   c DESC,
   d DESC,
   <dummy statement added at the end, so I don't need to remove the last comma>
```

From what I've read I cannot use ["ORDER BY 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445118/what-is-the-purpose-of-order-by-1-in-sql-select-statement), so does a similar hack actually exists?

Comment: Why `ORDER BY 1 desc, 2 desc, 3 desc, 4 desc` is not acceptable? MS SQL Server allow for such ordering.

Comment: @Renat an int literal in ORDER BY sorts by the column in ordinal position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could legally start every ORDER BY with something like:

```
order by @@spid
```

But it's likely to raise questions about query execution efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

What you said about not using "1" is only partially true.  If you did a similar pattern, adding "1" at the end would work as long as whatever column is in position 1 isn't also referenced in the `order by` clause.

I generally do something like this:

```
string whereClause = (list.Count > 0) 
                        ? "WHERE (" + list.StringJoin(") AND (") + ")"
                        : "";
```

where `StringJoin` is a very simple extension method I wrote.  Note the added parentheses so that if any of the list elements have an "OR" you don't get into trouble.

Something identical can be done for `ORDER BY`, just replacing the word `WHERE` above.

```
string orderClause = (list.Count > 0) 
                        ? "ORDER BY " + list.StringJoin(", ")
                        : "";
```

This is C# instead of c++, but a simple version of the extension method is this:

```
    public static string StringJoin(this IEnumerable<string> list, string separator)
    {
        if (list == null)
            return null;
        else
            return string.Join(separator, list.ToArray());
    }
```