# After doing union on same table, how to make first query results come on top?

Tags: sql, mysql

So, I am doing union on same table, **table1** with 2 different set of queries. My first query should return results with type 'test' and 2nd query should return results irrespective of type. But when Iam executing below query my first query results is not coming on top. Is there any way to achieve that such that it should always show first query execution results on top?

```
     select * from table1 where tl='AAA' AND FT ='ABC' AND DATE='04-MAY-23 11:07:00' AND TYPE = 'TEST'
 UNION
 select * from table1  where tl='AAA' AND FT ='ABC' AND DATE='04-MAY-23 11:07:00'
```

Comment: The concept of "top" exists only where you specify ordering, and you are not; If you don't require a *distinct* operation then use `union all` which might give your results as expected as it will avoid the data being sorted internally.

Comment: Does [Why and How do ORDER BY CASE Queries Work in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66878327/why-and-how-do-order-by-case-queries-work-in-sql-server) help?

Comment: I realise you may have simplified your queries for the purposes of this question, but I notice the criteria of your two `SELECT`s are almost identical.  If you just want the values where `TYPE = 'TEST'` to come at the top, you could just do `select * from table1  where tl='AAA' AND FT ='ABC' AND DATE='04-MAY-23 11:07:00' ORDER BY TYPE = 'TEST' DESC`

Comment: With `UNION [DISTINCT]` (instead of the more common `UNION ALL`) there is no longer "rows from the first or second query", as the process of removing duplicates has to mix both data sets and consider it a whole. You cannot even add a sortkey to the queries, as shown in Sahab's answer, because that would prevent the process from removing the duplicates.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, i.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Hope below query can help, we can set a order by value to fixed_number field and can do order by with that fixed_number field

```
select *, 1 as fixed_number  from table1 where tl='AAA'  AND FT ='ABC' AND DATE='04-MAY-23 11:07:00' AND TYPE = 'TEST'
UNION
select *, 2 as fixed_number  from table1  where tl='AAA' AND FT ='ABC' AND DATE='04-MAY-23 11:07:00'
ORDER BY fixed_number;
```

Comment: This will add rows to the result. (TYPE = 'TEST' rows will be duplicated.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this query produces a different result compared to the one in the question.

Comment: Can you please give me your table schema  with few insert row and give an idea of resulting row, so that i can investigate more.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 where tl='AAA' AND FT ='ABC' AND DATE='04-MAY-23 11:07:00' AND TYPE = 'TEST'
 UNION ALL
 select * from table1 where tl='AAA' AND FT ='ABC' AND DATE='04-MAY-23 11:07:00'
```

This was giving me expected results.
Thanks @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: How is this answer different to @Sahab answer?

Comment: sahab has done UNION which was giving all results, but results are not in the order which I needed, I need my first query results on top then second one...so UNION ALL was getting that.