# ORDER BY in DAXSTUDIO without specifying column name

Tags: dax, daxstudio

Is there a way in Daxstudio to sort table without specifying column name? This does not work:

```
EVALUATE
MyTable
ORDER BY 1
```

I am looking for the equivalent of SQL:

```
select * from MyTable
order by 1
```

Comment: I doubt there's an equivalent to [Order By 1 in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445118/what-is-the-purpose-of-order-by-1-in-sql-select-statement) in DAX, especially considering it's not considered good practice.

Comment: Maybe it is not a good practice in production plumbery but it is the quickest shot if you just want to explore the values of several columns of a table and have them sorted.