# Why Can't I Use Defined Variable in Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

My query is:

```
SELECT 
  offer, 
  (SELECT 
        AVG(offer) 
   FROM 
        project_bids
  ) as var1 
FROM 
  `project_bids` 
WHERE 
  offer > var1
```

It causes "#1054 - Unknown column 'var1' in 'where clause'" error. Can anybody expalain why gives that error ? (i know working sql but i want to learn why it fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of execution of clauses of a SELECT statement is mentioned here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/14/sql-server-easy-sequence-of-select-from-join-where-group-by-having-order-by/

Alias of an column can not be used in any clause except the last clause "ORDER BY".

Comment: nice answer. But you could have just edited your other answer.

Comment: I think the quoted order is wrong: the `SELECT` clause is resolved  between `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` -- this is why only the `ORDER BY` can reference a column's `AS` clause ('alias').

Comment: ...in fact, I'm almost sure that the article details the format of a `SELECT` clause (i.e. the sequence the clauses must be written in code) rather than the order of execution. See the last comment (by 'Martin').

Comment: Here's the correct order of execution https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841804/1542774

Answer (score 1):

you would have to move "var1" out of the `where` and put in it to a `having` statement

the `where` statement does not have access to columns created in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Write it as below:

SELECT offer, (SELECT AVG(offer) FROM project_bids) as var1 FROM `project_bids` WHERE offer > (SELECT AVG(offer) FROM project_bids)