# T-SQL Convert DateTime and Count entries for each date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am lost on how to solve what I believe should be a simple query.

I want to count the number of entries for each date in a table. The column `DateCreated` is in `DateTime` format. I can convert the `datetime` to date using

```
convert(VARCHAR, JobApps.DateCreated, 2) as Date
```

but with `COUNT(ID) as Qty` I get a count of 1 with multiple "Date" rows.

Here is the SQL query I am using.

```
SELECT  
    convert(VARCHAR, DateCreated, 2) as Date, COUNT(CompanyName) as Qty
FROM Apps  
GROUP BY DateCreated
ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
```

This is the results I get.

```
Date       Qty
------------------
13.05.29   1
13.05.29   1
13.05.29   1
13.05.29   1
13.05.29   1
13.05.28   1
13.05.28   1
13.05.27   1
13.05.27   1
```

etc...

What I wanting is a result like this...

```
Date       Qty
-----------------
13.05.29   5
13.05.28   2
13.05.27   2
```

etc...

Comment: Change `COUNT(CompanyName)` to `COUNT(DateCreated)` OR change all `DateCreated` to `CompanyName`

Comment: Wouldn't you have 2 for 13.05.28?

Comment: Yes, it was a type. It should have been 2 for 13.05.28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just gotta change your GROUP BY to use the actual value you want:

```
SELECT convert(VARCHAR, DateCreated, 2) as Date, COUNT(1) as Qty
FROM Apps
GROUP BY convert(VARCHAR, DateCreated, 2)
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: The query Zimdanen works by using ORDER BY convert(VARCHAR, DateCreated, 2) DESC (I guessed I could do that). Thanks for the explaination, I didn't know i could use the CONVERT statement in GROUP BY.

Comment: @StuRiaghain:  Should be able ORDER BY [Date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3841804/128217) DESC.