# GroupBy DAY using Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, group-by

I am looking for way to group my policies by day. I was trying a lot of examples how to do this but still there are some errors. Can anyone help me with this?
Here I will show only two examples, others i was trying were similar to those. Differences were only in used SQL's functions ex(CAST, SUBSTRING, DATE...)
First way i was trying is:

```
$query =  $this->getEntityManager()
                        ->createQueryBuilder();   
$query->select('count(p), p.transactionDate')
                        ->from('GLPolicyBundle:Policy', 'p')
                        ->andwhere('p.shop IN (:shop_id)')
                        ->setParameter('shop_id', $shop_list)
                        ->andWhere($query->expr()->between('p.transactionDate', ':date_from', ':date_to'))
                        ->setParameter('date_from', $date_from, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
                        ->setParameter('date_to', $date_to, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
                        ->addGroupBy('DAY(p.transactionDate)');
```

getDQL() returns:

```
SELECT count(p), p.transactionDate FROM GLPolicyBundle:Policy p 
WHERE p.shop IN (:shop_id) AND (p.transactionDate BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_to) 
GROUP BY DAY(p.transactionDate)
```

and the error is:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 156 near 'DAY(p.transa': Error: Cannot
>   group by undefined identification or result variable.

And the second way is:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT p,  (p.transactionDate) AS group
                            FROM GLPolicyBundle:Policy p
                            WHERE p.shop IN (:shop_id) AND (p.transactionDate BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_to) 
                            GROUP BY DAY(group)")
                            ->setParameter('shop_id', $shop_list)
                            ->setParameter('date_from', $date_from, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
                            ->setParameter('date_to', $date_to, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME);
```

getDQL() returns:

```
SELECT p, (p.transactionDate) AS group FROM GLPolicyBundle:Policy p 
WHERE p.shop IN (:shop_id) AND (p.transactionDate BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_to) 
GROUP BY DAY(group)
```

and the error is:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 72 near 'FROM GLPolicyBundle:Policy':
>   Error: Class 'FROM' is not defined.

Comment: in the second case try to use the ` character before and after `group`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine doesn't support many of the native db functions because it is supposed to work with many different types of databases.  So you're left with three options.

1. Use the `NativeQuery` class (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)
2. Implement a custom SQL walker.  Here is an example for grouping by day (https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Day.php)
3. Install a bundle that adds the grouping methods for you https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: Thanks for help, I used nativeQuery and it's working very well.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to use the DQL, there is a way to do it:

```
$query->select('count(p), p.transactionDate, SUBSTRING(p.transactionDate, 1, 10) as my_date')
    //...
    ->groupBy('my_date');
```

See the doc for [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

> SUBSTRING(str,pos,len). The forms with a len argument return a substring len characters long from string str, starting at position pos.

In my example, i start at position 1 to 10 which gives me YYYY-MM-DD. For instance, if you just want the day, you can start at position 9 with a length of 2

```
SUBSTRING(p.transactionDate, 9, 2)
```

Comment: Doing this against sql server didn't work (got unknown column), probably because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841804/4126114)

Comment: Doing `groupBy("substring(...)")` yields a Doctrine semantic error

Comment: Just filed doctrine2 [issue 6629](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6629)