# Group By day and month Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to list my users by birthday, so month and day but not year.

I have this query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE birthDate IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY MONTH(birthDate), DAY(birthDate)
```

But I don't know how to use it with Symfony and Doctrine.
I tried

```
$result = $em->getRepository("AcmeApplicationBundle:SecurityServiceUser")
            ->createQueryBuilder('user')
            ->where('user.birthDate IS NOT NULL')
            ->groupBy('MONTH(user.birthDate), DAY(user.birthDate)')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

And

```
$result = $em->getRepository("AcmeApplicationBundle:SecurityServiceUser")
            ->createQueryBuilder('user')
            ->where('user.birthDate IS NOT NULL')
            ->groupBy('MONTH(user.birthDate)')
            ->groupBy('DAY(user.birthDate)')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

But in both cases I have an error

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 165 near 'MONTH(birthDate),': Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable.

Comment: Maybe this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702674/groupby-day-using-doctrine2

Comment: Why do you have this query?

Comment: Did you install [https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions](Doctrine Extensions) ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You haven't set an alias for your values. Here is an updated version :

```
   $result = $em->getRepository("AcmeApplicationBundle:SecurityServiceUser")
        ->createQueryBuilder('user')
        ->select(' user.username, MONTH(user.birthDate) AS gBmonth, DAY(user.birthDate) AS gBday')
        ->where('user.birthDate IS NOT NULL')
        ->groupBy('gBmonth')
        ->addGroupBy('gBday')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Why do I have to select it first before I can group it

Comment: Ils very simple, like in a classic sql query, you have to define first your alias in select in order to use it with group

Comment: This throw me this error, why? `Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'my_database.o0_.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: You also need to install ´composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions´

Comment: @elvismdev, these links will likely help to understand: 1.) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html. 2.) https://medium.com/@riccardoodone/the-love-hate-relationship-between-select-and-group-by-in-sql-4957b2a70229

Answer (score -1):

You can use one of these:

```
format(as.Date,)
```

or

```
strftime(source, format)
```