# How do you group the SUM of rows by year in SQL

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT          YEAR(OrderDate) 'Year', SUM(TotalDue)
FROM            Sales
GROUP BY        OrderDate
Order BY        OrderDate
```

How do I add each year together as ONE row?
I wrote the query above, but the result still has the TotalDue by Year as individual rows.
For example

[image]

Comment: Please tag the RDMS you are using.

Answer (score 4):

You should `GROUP BY` Year, not OrderDate:

```
SELECT          YEAR(OrderDate), SUM(TotalDue)
FROM            Sales
GROUP BY        YEAR(OrderDate)
Order BY        OrderDate
```

Comment: Cannot use alias in GROUP because of query logical process

Comment: DId not work. Error: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: @Eda just provide alias for the year i.e. `YEAR(OrderDate) 'YEAR'` and in group by us `YEAR(OrderDate)`

OR

You can convert date format like `DATEPART(yyyy,OrderDate) 'YEAR'` and group by `DATEPART(yyyy,OrderDate)`

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem in the GROUP BY statement because it operates on a selected column:

```
SELECT YEAR(OrderDate) theYear, SUM(Due) TotalDue
FROM Sales
GROUP BY theYear --Here you can either order by TotalDue or by theYear,
                 -- otherwise you will get the errors you mentioned
```

Comment: @VDohnal it will work as long as the GROUP BY is performed on a selected column, which is my case.

Comment: @VDohnal yes, you are right (i even tried something else similar). My answer is wrong, you are right. Thank you for correcting me

Comment: But as I see it works in MySQL and Postgress, so it is not so bad after all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841295/sql-using-alias-in-group-by

Comment: @VDohnal Thank you again, but you are right, on Oracle it does not work. One way to make this work on Oracle is to select `OrderDate` too to use it for the `GROUP BY`. But the questioner needs 2 columns as a result, not 3, so we create what I said as a view, then from the view of 3 columns we pick the 2 columns he asked. Note that on Oracle `YEAR` is not accepted either. Thank you again for the useful comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should group by the year of the order date and no the OrderDate itself.

```
SELECT          YEAR(OrderDate) AS `Year`, SUM(TotalDue)
FROM            Sales
GROUP BY        YEAR(OrderDate)
Order BY        Year
```

Comment: THANK YOU Andrei. I created the RIGHT answer based on your input. Only the last line was eliminated, because it produced this Error message:Column "Sales.OrderDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY 
clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT          YEAR(OrderDate) 'Year', SUM(TotalDue)
FROM            Sales
GROUP BY        YEAR(OrderDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-group results

```
SELECT y, Sum(s) from 
  (
  SELECT          YEAR(OrderDate) as y , SUM(TotalDue) as s
    FROM            Sales
   GROUP BY        OrderDate
  )
group by y
Order BY y
```