# With what groupings am I supposed to think about joins?

Tags: sql, join, database-design, inner-join

I'm looking at the example

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

from W3Schools and am wondering how I'm supposed to group the clauses in my mind. From what I understand, every SQL query returns a table, and clauses within the query may themselves return a table. So I think of the whole

```
Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
```

as being a table and I'm returning a sub-table of it by applying `SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate` to it. Is that the right way to think about things?

Comment: You said :

`as being a table and I'm returning a sub-table of it by applying
 SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate`

The first part is correct. But I wouldn't say you are returning a sub-table from it. You're just grabbing the columns you want

Comment: Yeah. And best way to visualize it is by creating tables in database and `select * from` both tables one by one and see the data. Then use the join and how it is changing your output. And out of all those columns, just view the one you need.

If you don't have any db installed on your system, use `Head first SQL` hands on webpage or http://sqlfiddle.com/ . Once you start selecting tables and start putting where conditions and joins and see the output visually, then you will have a lot better understanding.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841295/sql-using-alias-in-group-by/3841485#3841485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of every query as if it composes a new temporary table with the result you want. This one takes rows from `Orders` and from `Customers`, matches them according to the `CustomerID` field in both tables (the `on` clause of the join), and then returns just several fields from `Orders` (`OrderID` and `OrderDate`) and one field from `Customers` (`CustomerName`).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are returning a new table containing all of the columns in your SELECT statement. If you simplify the query to:

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate
FROM Orders
```

You'd get a printout of the entire Orders table, but with only the two columns you specified.

With your INNER JOIN, you are filtering out the results to only include the Orders that have a CustomerID that matches a similar row in the Customers table with that same CustomerID. And with your SELECT statement, you are adding a column that shows the customer's name that is matched up with those orders.

So the ON part of the INNER JOIN is just matching customers to their respective orders. The SELECT part is where you are creating the new output table with the three columns you are interested in.

Does that help?