# ROW_NUMBER() SUB QUERY ISSUE

Tags: sql, subquery, row-number

I am trying to find activity during a specific time period.

there can and will be multiple records for one 'fileno' I want to limit that to one record.

```
SELECT   MASTER.FILENO, MASFORW.FORW_NO, MASTER.FORW_FILENO, 
         MASTER.COCO_FILENO, MASFORW.SORT_FIELD, TRACKUSR.trck_date, 
         TRACKUSR.whoami, TRACKUSR.track, TRACKUSR.rerite, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  MASTER.FILENO  
                            ORDER BY TRACKUSR.TRCK_DATE DESC) AS rownum
FROM    MASFORW 
INNER JOIN  MASTER 
        ON MASFORW.FORW_NO = MASTER.FORW_NO 
FULL OUTER JOIN TRACKUSR 
        ON MASTER.FILENO = TRACKUSR.fileno
WHERE (TRACKUSR.TRCK_DATE >= DATEADD(day, 0, GETDATE())) 
  AND (TRACKUSR.TRCK_DATE < DATEADD(day, 90, GETDATE())) 
  AND (MASFORW.SORT_FIELD = N'CR' OR
                         MASFORW.SORT_FIELD = N'CJ') 
  and (rownum = 1)
```

Comment: sorry,  error im getting is Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'rownum'.

Answer (score 0):

create a sub query and then filter rownum outside.

You cant use alias on the same query because at that moment you check the where the alias hasnt be created

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  MASTER.FILENO  
                                ORDER BY TRACKUSR.TRCK_DATE DESC) AS rownum
      FROM ...
     ) as subquery
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use an alias at the where clause...

there is a sql statement hierarchy..

1. from table
2. where clause
3. group by
4. having
5. select
6. order by

[related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841295/sql-using-alias-in-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of the query is ok, you can clear the error by replacing

```
and (rownum = 1)
```

with

```
having ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  MASTER.FILENO  
       ORDER BY TRACKUSR.TRCK_DATE DESC) = 1
```

Comment: It seems that `Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.`