# Is ordering done by actual column or alias?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a simple query like this:

```
select 
    subgroup,
    subgroup + ' (' + cast(grade as varchar(1)) + 'G)' as grade, 
    count(*) as 'count' 
From table_empl 
where year(EnterDate) = year(getdate())  
group by subgroup, grade  
order by grade
```

It seems that `order by grade` is being ordered by the alias `grade` instead of the actual column `grade;` at least that's what the result shows.

Is this correct?

Since I can't change the columns that are included in the result, is the solution to add an alias to the actual column? Something like this?

```
select 
    grade as 'grade2', 
    subgroup,
    subgroup + ' (' + cast(grade as varchar(1)) + 'G)' as grade,
    count(*) as 'count'
From table_empl 
where year(EnterDate) = year(getdate())  
group by subgroup,grade  
order by grade2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3841804/6167855

Comment: The column aliases will take precedence over actual columns in case of any ambiguity. I unfortunately cannot find definitive proof of this in Books Online. If you wanted to make sure the actual column is used, you can prefix it in the order by - `ORDER BY table_empl.grade`

Comment: Can you elaborate @GarethD

Comment: weird situations like this is why I make sure that my aliases don't collide with the column names in the tables I'm selecting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefix the column name by its table name (or an alias given to the table in the `FROM` clause) in the `ORDER BY` clause, then it will use the column, not the expression computed in the `SELECT` clause and given the same name as the column.

So this should sort using the original `grade` column:

```
select 
    subgroup,
    subgroup + ' (' + cast(grade as varchar(1)) + 'G)' as grade, 
    count(*) as 'count' 
From table_empl 
where year(EnterDate) = year(getdate())  
group by subgroup, grade  
order by table_empl.grade
```

Or:

```
select 
    subgroup,
    subgroup + ' (' + cast(grade as varchar(1)) + 'G)' as grade, 
    count(*) as 'count' 
From table_empl t
where year(EnterDate) = year(getdate())  
group by subgroup, grade  
order by t.grade
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, it makes sense. It's incredible, but it never passed through my mind to prefix the column name.

Comment: @rbhatup - realized I'd screwed up the examples and changed it in `GROUP BY` rather than `ORDER BY`, and have now corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Instruction Order By runs after all instructions, even Select. And in this case it's correct to take alias instead actual column.

The clauses are processed in the following order:

```
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
ORDER BY
```

You can use name(Alias) of table to specify table column

Answer (score 0):

A very good question. Apparently, the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) does not provide a direct answer to it. However, one can imply the observed behaviour from the following fact: the difference between column alias and column is that the latter can be prefixed with its parent table name (alias), whereas the former cannot.

Since you didn't specify the table name in the `ORDER BY` clause, the column alias takes root.