# Group by not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Group by is not working, may be because I am using mathematical expression in the select option.

```
select FLOOR(SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkin_date,rd.created_at))/COUNT(DATEDIFF(rd.checkin_date,rd.created_at))) AS names, 
COUNT(rd.id) as totbooking, 
SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkout_date,rd.checkin_date)) AS nights, 
round(SUM(CASE WHEN h.currency_id=151 THEN rd.total_cents WHEN h.currency_id!=151 THEN rd.total_cents/cur.exchange_rate ELSE 0 END)/100) AS revenue, 
round((round(SUM(CASE WHEN h.currency_id=151 THEN rd.total_cents WHEN h.currency_id!=151 THEN rd.total_cents/cur.exchange_rate ELSE 0 END)/100)) / (SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkout_date,rd.checkin_date)))) as adr, FLOOR((FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN h.currency_id=151 THEN rd.total_cents WHEN h.currency_id!=151 THEN rd.total_cents/cur.exchange_rate ELSE 0 END)/100)) / COUNT(rd.id)) as atp, FLOOR(SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkin_date,rd.created_at))/COUNT(DATEDIFF(rd.checkin_date,rd.created_at))) as leadtime, 
SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkout_date,rd.checkin_date)) / (COUNT(rd.id)) as alos, (SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkout_date,rd.checkin_date)) / (h.total_rooms * 31))*100 as share from `reservation_details` as `rd` 
left join `hotels` as `h` on `rd`.`hotel_id` = `h`.`id` 
left join `currencies` as `cur` on `cur`.`id` = `h`.`currency_id` 
left join `chains` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `h`.`chain_id`
where `rd`.`status` >= 50 and date(rd.created_at) >= "2017-04-30" and date(rd.created_at) <= "2017-05-30" GROUP BY names
```

Comment: Could your format that? It's impossible to read

Comment: No errors shown? I call it working then.

Comment: @nacho   please check now

Comment: @Chay22 it throwing "Can't group on 'names' " to me ......

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841295/sql-using-alias-in-group-by

Comment: This question still needs an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don you try it this way? It would help if you let us see some data

```
select names,sum(totbooking),sum(nights),sum(revenue),sum(adr),leadtime,sum(alos),sum(share)
from (
    select FLOOR(SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkin_date,rd.created_at))/COUNT(DATEDIFF(rd.checkin_date,rd.created_at))) AS names, COUNT(rd.id) as totbooking, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkout_date,rd.checkin_date)) AS nights,round(SUM(CASE WHEN h.currency_id=151 THEN rd.total_cents WHEN h.currency_id!=151 THEN rd.total_cents/cur.exchange_rate ELSE 0 END)/100) AS revenue, 
    round((round(SUM(CASE WHEN h.currency_id=151 THEN rd.total_cents WHEN h.currency_id!=151 THEN rd.total_cents/cur.exchange_rate ELSE 0 END)/100)) / (SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkout_date,rd.checkin_date)))) as adr, FLOOR((FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN h.currency_id=151 THEN rd.total_cents WHEN h.currency_id!=151 THEN rd.total_cents/cur.exchange_rate ELSE 0 END)/100)) / COUNT(rd.id)) as atp, FLOOR(SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkin_date,rd.created_at))/COUNT(DATEDIFF(rd.checkin_date,rd.created_at))) as leadtime, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkout_date,rd.checkin_date)) / (COUNT(rd.id)) as alos, (SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkout_date,rd.checkin_date)) / (h.total_rooms * 31))*100 as share 
    from `reservation_details` as `rd` 
    left join `hotels` as `h` on `rd`.`hotel_id` = `h`.`id` 
    left join `currencies` as `cur` on `cur`.`id` = `h`.`currency_id` 
    left join `chains` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `h`.`chain_id`
    where `rd`.`status` >= 50 and date(rd.created_at) >= "2017-04-30" and date(rd.created_at) <= "2017-05-30" )
group by names
```

Comment: it returning single row, but i want the list @nacho

Comment: @Rakesh Tripathi It would help a lot if you upload some tables with data to see what you need

Answer (score 0):

You are using alias, so in the `GROUP BY` clause you should use it too
I supose `names` belongs to `hotels` so you need to do it this way

```
GROUP BY h.names
```

Comment: his "names" means `FLOOR(SUM(DATEDIFF(rd.checkin_date, rd.created_at)) / COUNT(DATEDIFF(rd.checkin_date, rd.created_at))) AS names`

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see it

Comment: @RakeshTripathi pls re-format your querry, use code syntax