# Use of alias - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Quick question.  I'm running through an SQL challenge and it seems to me that using an Alias works in some instances, but not in others.  It seems arbitrary, but I know I'm missing something.

Consider Code A:

```
Select DOW = datename(dw, orderdate), Revenue = sum(subtotal), Orders = count(*), RPO = sum(subtotal) from sales.salesorderheader
where year(orderdate) = 2008
and OnlineOrderFlag = 0
Group by datename(dw, orderdate)
Order by RPO desc
```

That works just fine.  I like that in the Order by part of the code, I can refer to sum(subtotal) by the Alias Revenue.

If I try to do the same with the Group By line, it doesn't work.  I.e. the following doesn't work:

```
Select DOW = datename(dw, orderdate), Revenue = sum(subtotal), Orders = count(*), RPO = sum(subtotal) from sales.salesorderheader
where year(orderdate) = 2008
and OnlineOrderFlag = 0
Group by DOW
Order by RPO desc
```

Why can I use the alias with the Order by clause, but not hte Group by clause?  I'm forced to type out the full "Group by datename(dw, orderdate)"

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - using alias in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841295/sql-using-alias-in-group-by)

Comment: It's the order in which the [clauses are processed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70efeffe-76b9-4b7e-b4a1-ba53f5d21916/order-of-execution-of-sql-queries?forum=transactsql). In other words, the `group by` clause gets processed before the `select` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct behavior for SQL Server.  Some databases allow aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  SQL Server is not one of them.

Databases are also inconsistent about aliases in the `HAVING` clause.  However, most databases allow aliases in the `ORDER BY` -- some (such as Hive) even require aliases there, not allowing functional expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `cross apply` if you don't want to repeat the expression twice

```
SELECT ca.DOW,
       Revenue = Sum(subtotal),
       Orders = Count(*),
       RPO = Sum(subtotal)
FROM   sales.salesorderheader
       CROSS apply (SELECT Datename(dw, orderdate)) ca (DOW)
WHERE  Year(orderdate) = 2008
       AND OnlineOrderFlag = 0
GROUP  BY ca.DOW
ORDER  BY RPO DESC
```