# Getting error Invalid column name days in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on sql query, When i run the query i am getting error `Invalid column name 'days'.`, Can anyone please help me, why i am getting error like this, it looks like there something issue with having, but still not able to resolve it, here is my query

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ABS(DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), EpStart)) AS [days]
    FROM tb_Episode
    HAVING [days] <= ''
) AS episodes 
WHERE
    (episodes.EOEClaimDate is NULL or episodes.EOEClaimDate = '0000-00-00') AND
    episodes.PayerType = 'Ep' AND
    episodes.EpEnd < '2018-02-05' AND
    episodes.CustID = '27'
```

Comment: you cannot use the *alias* in the `having` clause. you must use the calculated form itself. eg :`abs(DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), EpStart)) <= ''` the column `days` can only be used in the outer query (outside subquery). You also need to use `WHERE` and not `HAVING` - `WHERE abs(DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), EpStart)) <= ''`

Comment: .. and also change having to `where`

Comment: Scope issue. Move it to outside the sub-query: `WHERE  [days] <= '' AND...`

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense to compare a numerical quantity against empty string.  What is your logic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use in `HAVING` clause the alias of your field.

Why you use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`?

The same restriction for `HAVING` exists for `WHERE`,

So your query will become:

```
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ABS(DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), EpStart)) AS [days]
    FROM tb_Episode
    WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), EpStart)) <= ''
) AS episodes
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841804/7147233) by @Codo you cannot using a `HAVING` on an alias/virtual column as each SQL clause is performed in a designated order

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

So because your column alias is defined after the `HAVING` clause you get the invalid column name error as the column doesn't technically exist yet.