# Postgresql clause priority

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why group by clause use 'month' alias and works? I thought 'select' clause is executed after 'group by'. Am i right that functions are executed before any clauses?

```
select date_trunc('month', starttime) as month, count(*)
    from cd.bookings
    group by month
order by month
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841804/3270427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` is not executed after `group by`.  It is not before either.

A SQL query expresses the *result set* that the database operations are supposed to produce.  In fact, the actual processing is typically a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of dataflow operations -- very far from the clauses in the SQL query itself.

The ANSI standard specifies that the logic ordering of interpreting aliases.  In general, the aliases defined in the `select` are not available for the `where` and `group by` clauses, for instance.

However, some databases extend the scoping rules (MySQL is another) and allow the use of such aliases in the `group by`.  This is considered a *feature*.  But it can result in misleading interpretations when a column alias conflicts with the name of a column in a table.