# Why am I getting "Invalid column name" error when the column exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

This is my code:

```
declare @maxsnap table (sita varchar(10), date date, SNAPSHOT_DATE date)

insert into @maxsnap 
   select 
       sita, date, max(SNAPSHOT_DATE) snapshot 
   from 
       [UKRMC].[dbo].[Roll_forecast] 
   where 
       date between '2018-03-21' and '2018-05-31'
   group by 
       sita, date 

select 
    roll.DATE, roll.SITA,
    contacts.rooms,
    roll.SEGMENT, roll.RNS 
from 
    [UKRMC].[dbo].[Roll_forecast] roll
join 
    [UKRMC].[dbo].[Contacts] contacts on contacts.SITA = roll.SITA
join 
    @maxsnap snap on roll.DATE = snap.date 
                  and roll.SITA = snap.sita 
                  and roll.SNAPSHOT_DATE = snap.snapshot
where 
    roll.date between '2018-03-21' and '2018-05-31'
```

The error I am getting is

> Invalid column name 'snapshot'

when I join the `@maxnsap` table variable. But that column does exist!

Comment: did you mean `max(SNAPSHOT_DATE) AS snapshot` in your `SELECT`?

Comment: @Forty3 I've tried that and it still gives me the same error

Comment: @maxsnap doesn't have the column `snapshot` so this doesn't work `roll.SNAPSHOT_DATE = snap.snapshot`

Comment: Sorry - you define the table `@maxsnap` with a column named `SNAPSHOT_DATE` not `snapshot`. So in your final `SELECT` you need to refer to `snap.SNAPSHOT_DATE`

Comment: yep @Forty3 explained it better than me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in join

```
     and roll.SNAPSHOT_DATE = snap.SNAPSHOT_DATE
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! However, I called it 'snapshot' so it doesn't make sense to me why I need to refer to the original column name

Comment: The column in the @maxsnap  table is called SNAPSHOT_DATE.  In your query to populate the table you've used the alias snapshot but this doesn't change the name of the column in the table

Comment: @Sorath you cannot use the alias name as to the compiler the alias hasn't been assigned yet, if you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841804/7147233) it explains that each section of the select statement in ran in an order of precedence, stating that the from is done before the select

Comment: That alias only existed for the initial `insert` and even there it was ignored. Since you didn't specify a column list it just assumed the columns in the same order as you created the table.

Answer (score 1):

You have this condition:

```
roll.DATE = snap.date
```

However, the column is called `snapshot_date`:

```
roll.DATE = snap.snapshot_date
```