# Doubts on Group By with ALias

Tags: postgresql, group-by

```
SELECT
    first_name || ' ' || last_name full_name,
    SUM (amount) amount
FROM
    payment
INNER JOIN customer USING (customer_id)     
GROUP BY
    full_name
ORDER BY amount;
```

Can i know how does this query works for group by full_name, by rigth the query should give error because of the order of the sql execution(https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841804/15279872).  The output of the above query can  be seen in this link (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/) under the Section 3 : Using PostgreSQL GROUP BY clause with the JOIN clause

Comment: But how can the query gives the output without showing any error at the group by clause

Answer (score 3):

Here is what [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#id-1.9.3.171.10.9) says about GROUP BY in PostgreSQL:

> In the SQL-92 standard, an ORDER BY clause can only use output column
> names or numbers, while a GROUP BY clause can only use expressions
> based on input column names. PostgreSQL extends each of these clauses
> to allow the other choice as well (but it uses the standard's
> interpretation if there is ambiguity). PostgreSQL also allows both
> clauses to specify arbitrary expressions. Note that names appearing in
> an expression will always be taken as input-column names, not as
> output-column names.
>
> SQL:1999 and later use a slightly different definition which is not
> entirely upward compatible with SQL-92. In most cases, however,
> PostgreSQL will interpret an ORDER BY or GROUP BY expression the same
> way SQL:1999 does.

The “output column name” mentioned above can be an alias, so PostgreSQL allows aliases in the `GROUP BY` clause.