# DB2 Error Combining Case, Aggregation, Alias, and Group By

Tags: sql, db2-luw

This is part of a much larger query, but this snippet shows the error.  Without the aggregation and Group by, the statement works.  Once I add the aggregation and group by, I get this error:

1. [Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  "COMPANYN" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.22.29
2. [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-206", SQLSTATE "42703" and message tokens "COMPANYN".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.22.29

Below is the SQL:

```
SELECT s.SERVICE_NAME servicename,
       CASE
           WHEN (r.company IS NULL
                 OR r.company = ''
                 OR r.company = 'BTS')
                AND r.CREATED_BY like '%JBlake%' THEN 'ABC'
           ELSE r.company
       END companyN,
           r.CREATED_BY,
           count(1) NoOfHits
FROM ac.SSO_REQUEST r,
     ac.SSO_SERVICE s
WHERE s.id = r.DSO_SERVICE_ID
  AND r.CREATE_DATE > TO_DATE('06302018', 'MMDDYYYY')
  AND r.CREATE_DATE < TO_DATE('07012019', 'MMDDYYYY')
group by s.SERVICE_NAME, companyN, r.CREATED_BY
```

If I comment out the aggregation and group by, the query works.  I think the alias of **companyN** is causing a problem in the group by.

```
SELECT s.SERVICE_NAME servicename,
       CASE
           WHEN (r.company IS NULL
                 OR r.company = ''
                 OR r.company = 'BTS')
                AND r.CREATED_BY like '%JBlake%' THEN 'ABC'
           ELSE r.company
       END companyN,
           r.CREATED_BY--,
           --count(1) NoOfHits
FROM ac.SSO_REQUEST r,
     ac.SSO_SERVICE s
WHERE s.id = r.DSO_SERVICE_ID
  AND r.CREATE_DATE > TO_DATE('06302018', 'MMDDYYYY')
  AND r.CREATE_DATE < TO_DATE('07012019', 'MMDDYYYY')
--group by s.SERVICE_NAME, companyN, r.CREATED_BY
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers my question:
[sql-using-alias-in-group-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841295/sql-using-alias-in-group-by#:%7E:text=SQL%20Server%20doesn%27t%20allow%20you%20to%20reference%20the,use%20the%20alias%20in%20the%20ORDER%20BY%20clause.)