# In Presto query is it possible to refer column name rathen then the whole syntax

Tags: sql, presto

This is my query

```
SELECT regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1') as Path, 
COUNT(regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1')) as countreq
FROM "tk_logs"."services-june" 
WHERE url_extract_host(request_url) IN ('website1.com','website2.com')
GROUP BY regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1')
ORDER BY count(regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1')) desc
```

When I run same query like

```
SELECT regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1') as Path, 
COUNT(regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1')) as countreq
FROM "tk_logs"."services-june" 
WHERE url_extract_host(request_url) IN ('website1.com','website2.com')
GROUP BY Path
ORDER BY countreq desc
```

I get error

```
Column 'Path' cannot be resolved
```

Usually in mysql query this is allowed. For Presto am I supposed to do it some other way?

Sample MySql query

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) as cust_count, Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY cust_count;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - using alias in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841295/sql-using-alias-in-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, you need either do subselect:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1') as Path, 
        regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1') as countreq
    FROM "tk_logs"."services-june" 
    WHERE url_extract_host(request_url) IN ('website1.com','website2.com')
)
GROUP BY Path
ORDER BY count(countreq)
```

Or refer them by index, which is considered not a best practice though:

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1') as Path, 
COUNT(regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1')) as countreq
FROM "tk_logs"."services-june" 
WHERE url_extract_host(request_url) IN ('website1.com','website2.com')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 desc
```

P.S.

Note that unless you are doing distinct count `COUNT(regexp_replace(url_extract_path(request_url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1')) as countreq` should not differ from `count(request_url)`.