How to perform query in a simpler way?
I faced a problem in the interview (it is over now).
There is table salary like this:
ID   SALARY
-----------
1    20000
2    30000
3    90000
...

I need to construct table which will classify salaries into groups and count number in each one of them. The classification is
if salary < 50000, then `low_salary`
if 50000 <= salary < 80000, then `medium_salary`
if salary >= 80000 then `high_salary`

The structure would be something like
Group_name      cnt
-------------------
low_salary      20
medium_salary   40
high_salary     30

My solution was
WITH tmp AS 
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        CASE 
            WHEN salary < 50000 THEN 'low_salary'
            WHEN salary >= 50000 AND salary < 80000 THEN 'medium_salary'
            ELSE 'high_salary'
        END AS group_name
    FROM 
        salary
)
SELECT group_name, COUNT(id) 
FROM tmp
GROUP BY group_name

I used a CTE because I was not sure that I would be able to perform GROUP BY by the aliased CASE column, defined in select (please specify if that is true).
The interviewers said that it would be correct, however it is too complex, and there are two "conceptually simpler" solutions. They didn't disclose it. So how could I do it "conceptually" simpler? I suppose it means not using GROUP BY and CASE since they were surprised to see it.
So I wonder if there really is a much simpler solution....

sql tag is not enough, You must identify DB engine because different engines have different ability to do these things

I don't see how the proposed query is too complex, I would find difficult to find any simpler alternative. Maybe they're looking for a very specific solution?

@T.S. It is general question, DB engine was not specified. I don't suppose it is a trick and solution is generic enough to be correct on all popular engines

@Alejandro, the interviewer mentioned that one of the solutions is specific for this problem, but it is concise and "very naive"

If you are supposed to produce those three rows with the group name and count columns, then your query is as simple as it gets. The only part that you could simplify a bit is changing the order in the case expresssion: < 50000, >= 80000, else. Thus you don't have to repeat the 50000 which makes the query a tad easier to maintain should the ranges be subject to change. You could do without a CTE, but the CTE makes the query easier to read, and easier to read = simpler, too, in my opinion. And COUNT(id) can be changed to COUNT(*) in order to tell the DBMS that it only has to count rows.

The best solution puts this is one row instead of three and uses conditional aggregation:
SELECT 
    sum(case when salary  < 50000 then 1 end) low_salary,
    sum(case when salary >= 50000 and salaray <80000 then 1 end) medium_salary,
    sum(case when salary >= 80000 then 1 end) high_salary
FROM salary

This will tend to perform better and is clearly much less code.
If you really need three rows, I'd do this:
select
    case when s.salary < 50000 then 'low_salary' 
         when s.salary < 80000 then 'medium_salary'
         else 'high_salary' end group_name,
    , count(id) [cnt]
from salary
group by case when s.salary < 50000 then 'low_salary' 
              when s.salary < 80000 then 'medium_salary'
              else 'high_salary' end

Note some databases may allow you use the group_name identifier in the group by clause, but SQL Server (at least) makes you repeat yourself. This also still uses both group by and case, but at least it reduces nesting.
The only other way to get rows is connecting with a set that has three rows, but the code for that will be even more complicated, not less, which defeats the purpose.

This looks very nice, but it has different structure than desired one. Is there a clean way to turn result of this query which is 1x3 to desired output in form 3x2?

Note: If you don't use a ELSE 0 clause in your sum, the sum will return NULL if no values are found. Either use COUNT rather than SUM or add ELSE 0, unless you really want to return NULL in this case.

@Nourless Why do you care about the structure of the result? Usually, the best way is to execute the most performant query and then use your application to do something with the result or change its structure.

@JonasMetzler, it is due to interview's formulation of a problem, I was given structure of desired result. The solution proposed here is essentially like mine, so I really wonder what they could mean by "more simpler solution"...

Solution without CASE or GROUP. Works for SQL-Server, MySQL, MariaDB, and Postgress.
SELECT  'low_salary' as group_name, COUNT(*) as GroupCount  FROM salary WHERE salary < 50000 
UNION ALL  
SELECT  'Medium_salary' as group_name, COUNT(*) as GroupCount  FROM salary WHERE salary between 50000 and 80000
UNION ALL
SELECT  'high_salary' as group_name, COUNT(*) as GroupCount  FROM salary WHERE salary > 80000 

fiddle



group_name
GroupCount




low_salary
2


Medium_salary
0


high_salary
1




Is it more memory or time efficient than the one given by me?

@Nourless: The solution gives different results (yours does not show Medium_salary), so comparison of memory or time efficiency is pretty useless.

It is so on dummy example, when all three are present, they should yield the same result no? Especially if ORDER BY is added. I mean, supposing it is the desired solution, by which metric could it be simpler than mine? It seems that speaking about execution yours would be more complex since it is three searches over table?

@Nourless: You could always compare the execution plans (on a better dataset ) see: https://dbfiddle.uk/gDNi7FZ5 where Estimated Subtree Cost is lower on the last query

@Nourless - For efficiency it depends on whether or not salary is indexed. If it isn't indexed this just scans the data three times. If it is indexed it can just seek each range and count it. But "conceptually simpler" doesn't imply anything about query efficiency to me. And TBH is subjective.

select 
    case 
        when salary < 50000 then 'low_salary'
        when salary >=50000 AND salary < 80000 then 'medium_salary' 
        else 'high_salary'
    end as salary_type
    ,count(*) as count
from salary
group by salary_type;


Firstly, I would like to point out that it is hard to read code in text format, can you format it please? And secondly it is essentially my solution, but you do grouping on aliased column, which, I think, won't work

Was missing a comma. Also, if you want answers to get votes here, you'll take the time to format the code so it gets syntax highlighting and has good indentation/formatting. Also, that it actually works (broken for most database types even with the missing comma)

From:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841804/724039   : SQL - using alias in Group By: There are exceptions though: MySQL and Postgres seem to have additional smartness that allows it.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?


Perhaps using a subquery instead of a CTE would seem like an easier solution.(Although in fact there is no difference).

select group_name,count(*) cnt
from(
  select
    case when salary < 50000 then 'low_salary' 
         when salary < 80000 then 'medium_salary'
    else 'high_salary' 
    end group_name
  from salary s
) t
group by group_name

Another simplification is that (perhaps) there are no duplicates (by id) in the table. Therefore, count(*) can be applied.

Without group by

select group_name
 ,case when group_name='low_salary' then cnt-s5
       when group_name='medium_salary' then s5-s8
       when group_name='high_salary' then s8
  end group_cnt
from
 (
 select 
   count(*) cnt
  ,sum(case when salary >= 50000 then 1 else 0 end) s5
  ,sum(case when salary >= 80000 then 1 else 0 end) s8
from salary
) tc
left join (select 'low_salary' group_name union all select 'medium_salary' union all select 'high_salary') g on 1=1

Works where some group is missing.
