T-SQL claim subquery returns more than one value yet the data is unique
I am using SQL Server 2012. I couldn't find a similar problem in other places, and I am still learning SQL.
I am trying to get a subquery to return one value. My table JobMilestones is unique when you compare JobPaperID AND Milestone. Any independent query will return only one value or no values.
I get this error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

The rest of the query is giving the right results when I don't add the subquery, however I do need the subquery as well. In the table JobMilestones I'll either have an entry for a specific job which has a unique JobPaperID AND a unique Milestone (taken together), or I'll have no entry (I am suspecting the latter is the problem). I expect the subquery to return CompletedDate or to return a single NULL value if the record doesn't exist. I expect it to return a single NULL (where there are no records) or the value of CompletedDate. Where am I going wrong?
This is the code I am using:
SELECT 
    mjd.ID AS JobID,
    mjd.JobNo AS JobNo, 
    mjd.CreateDateTime AS JobCreatedDateTime, 
    mjd.InvoiceCustomerCode AS CustomerCode, 
    mjd.MilestoneGroup AS MilestoneGroup, 
    mg.Name AS MilestoneGroupDescr, 
    ml.MilestoneID AS MilestoneID, 
    CASE m.CustomType
        WHEN 0 THEN m.Type
        ELSE m.CustomType
    END AS MilestoneReal, 
    m.Name AS MilestoneName,
    jp.ID AS JobPaperID, 
    jp.Name AS JobPaperName,
    (SELECT jms.CompletedDate
     FROM dbo.JobMilestones AS jms
     WHERE ((jms.JobPaperID = jp.ID) 
       AND (jms.Milestone = MilestoneReal))) AS CompletedDate
FROM 
    dbo.MainJobDetails AS mjd
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MilestoneGroup AS mg ON mjd.MilestoneGroup = mg.Code
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.JobPaper AS jp ON mjd.ID = jp.JobID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MilestoneLink AS ml ON mg.ID = ml.MilestoneGroupID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Milestones AS m ON ml.MilestoneID = m.ID
WHERE 
    mjd.ID = 87101 

If I change it to SELECT TOP 1, all I get is NULL and none of the valid entries

jms.Milestone = Milestone is wrong, it's same as 1 = 1, you probably need: jms.Milestone = m.Milestone or whatever. But why not just LEFT join if it's all unique as you say? No need for subquery

It's closer to jms.Milestone IS NOT NULL, @siggemannen, but yes. Classic "Not a bug".

jms.Milestone iis from JobMilestones.Milestone while Milestone is a result of the CASE statement. Maybe I should name it different.

You can't reference the alias defined in the CASE statement there anyway.

Edited to remove that confusion.

The "confusion" is the answer for your question though, you were hoping that it would use the value from the CASE statement. Instead it was being treated as jms.Milestone = jms.Milestone - If you try and run your edited statement you will find that MilestoneReal is not in scope

@MartinSmith is there any way I can access those results? The way the tables have been designed (by external consultant) is such that to find a valid Milestone I have to carry out that comparison.

just repeat the CASE expression. It is only short

That worked. Thank you very much @MartinSmith
I am now curious. How would I go round it if the case was a long complicated one? Is there a way of accessing the value without having to repeat the 'CASE'?

@Ssem/kulaMukiibi To avoid repetition like that you can use a CTE or a cross apply.

CROSS APPLY example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41128611/73226

Still wonder why you need a subquery, a LEFT JOIN looks more natural

fyi, SQL Server 2012 have been fully end of life for about 2 years now. That means it hasn't had any updates in a long time... not even critical security patches. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using this: updating to a supported edition is job #1.

@MartinSmith a left join would return results of too many records, even those that are not relevant. That was my first trial. It returned more null records than are valid for this scenario.

Agreed @JoelCoehoorn. However that decision is sitting in accounts waiting for approval. In the region I am the cost of upgrading is relatively high and it's not a decision that can be taken lightly by finance, especially when they see the current platform is "working".

I think you meant to ping @siggemannen as I have never enquired about a left join

No it wouldn't ,since if it returned more than one record, your subquery would fail with the above error. Oh well

Sorry @siggemannen. I meant to ping you. However I did finally work out a left join that would work. It's a bit complex but surprisingly works better than the earlier example. I think I'll put it here as an answer for anybody who may have a similar problem.

Thanks to @Martin Smith the solution appears simple:
SELECT 
    mjd.ID as JobID,
    mjd.JobNo as JobNo, 
    mjd.CreateDateTime as JobCreatedDateTime, 
    mjd.InvoiceCustomerCode as CustomerCode, 
    mjd.MilestoneGroup as MilestoneGroup, 
    mg.Name as MilestoneGroupDescr, 
    ml.MilestoneID as MilestoneID, 
    case m.CustomType
        when 0 then m.Type
        else m.CustomType
    end AS MilestoneReal, 
    m.Name as MilestoneName,
    jp.ID as JobPaperID, 
    jp.Name as JobPaperName,
    (select jms.CompletedDate
        from dbo.JobMilestones AS jms
        where ((jms.JobPaperID = jp.ID) 
            AND (jms.Milestone = 
                    case m.CustomType
                        when 0 then m.Type
                        else m.CustomType
                    end))
    ) AS CompletedDate
FROM dbo.MainJobDetails AS mjd
INNER JOIN dbo.MilestoneGroup AS mg
    ON mjd.MilestoneGroup = mg.Code
INNER JOIN dbo.JobPaper AS jp 
    ON mjd.ID = jp.JobID
INNER JOIN dbo.MilestoneLink AS ml 
    ON mg.ID = ml.MilestoneGroupID
INNER JOIN dbo.Milestones AS m 
    ON ml.MilestoneID = m.ID
WHERE mjd.ID = 87101

Alas! I cannot use the alias in the subquery.

For the sake of completeness (and because it is faster especially when I remove the where clause) I'll put this here. It works but it's a bit more complex than I hoped. Maybe somebody can simplify it.
SELECT 
    mjd.ID AS JobID,
    mjd.JobNo AS JobNo, 
    mjd.CreateDateTime AS JobCreatedDateTime, 
    mjd.InvoiceCustomerCode AS CustomerCode, 
    mjd.MilestoneGroup AS MilestoneGroup, 
    mg.Name AS MilestoneGroupDescr, 
    ml.MilestoneID AS MilestoneID, 
    CASE m.CustomType
        WHEN 0 THEN m.Type
        ELSE m.CustomType
    END AS Milestone, 
    m.Name AS MilestoneName,
    jp.ID AS JobPaperID, 
    jp.Name AS JobPaperName,
    jmsq.RequiredDate AS RequiredDate,
    jmsq.CompletedDate AS CompletedDate
FROM dbo.MainJobDetails AS mjd
INNER JOIN dbo.MilestoneGroup AS mg
    ON mjd.MilestoneGroup = mg.Code
INNER JOIN dbo.JobPaper AS jp 
    ON mjd.ID = jp.JobID
INNER JOIN dbo.MilestoneLink AS ml 
    ON mg.ID = ml.MilestoneGroupID
INNER JOIN dbo.Milestones AS m 
    ON ml.MilestoneID = m.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        jm.CompletedDate, 
        jm.RequiredDate,
        jm.Milestone,
        jm.JobPaperID
        FROM dbo.JobMilestones AS jm
        INNER JOIN dbo.Milestones AS msb 
            ON jm.Milestone = 
                CASE msb.CustomType
                    WHEN 0 THEN msb.Type
                    ELSE msb.CustomType
                END
        INNER JOIN dbo.JobPaper AS jpb 
            ON jm.JobPaperID = jpb.ID
    )  AS jmsq
    ON jmsq.JobPaperID = jp.ID
        AND jmsq.Milestone = CASE m.CustomType 
                                WHEN 0 THEN m.type 
                                ELSE m.CustomType
                            END
WHERE mjd.ID = 87101

