# Meaning of Integer in GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am testing and trying to understand and tweak a large query written by someone else, would like some help with the meaning of an integer in the GROUP BY section. It has the following structure:

```
SELECT
  column1,
  column2,
  SUM(column3),
  SUM(column4),
FROM
  table1 AS a
WHERE 
  column5 <> 3
GROUP BY
  column1,
  7,
  column2;
```

What does that 7 do? I can't really find it anywhere in the output, or see what effect it has had.

Comment: Possibly already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380002/what-do-comma-separated-integers-in-a-group-by-statement-accomplish).

Comment: Does this query works? possible duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380002/what-do-comma-separated-integers-in-a-group-by-statement-accomplish)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do comma-separated integers in a GROUP BY statement accomplish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380002/what-do-comma-separated-integers-in-a-group-by-statement-accomplish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of the `SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) explains:

> Columns selected for output can be referred to in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses using column names, column aliases, or column positions.
>   Column positions are integers and begin with 1.

`GROUP BY 7` in your query is not a valid column position because the `SELECT` clause contains only `4` expressions.

Comment: Ok thanks, well as I did not know what it meant, only wrote out 4 things in the select statement. The real query contains 14 things in the select statement, and I observe if I change the 7 to a 14, it still works, but a 15 causes an error. OK, **columns selected for output** which can be not just the columns but `CONCAT(column6, column7)` for example, not columns in the original table, but **selected for output**

Comment: That's because there is no "the 15th column" in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 2):

When any integer value is used on `Group by`, it means to group by the 7th column. Same can be done with `ORDER BY`

I assumed that you have provided the code for sample in your actual code you must have 7 or more than 7 columns in `SELECT` clause

Answer (score 0):

The integer values used in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are the position of the columns starting from 1 ( sorry array's counting system ;) ).

You can look more of it on the official documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).